# Blender denoise node not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, denoise

This feature has not been working in my laptop since it came out. Basically what happens is when I add the denoiser to the render layer in compositor ,it hangs my laptop for roughly the same amount of time it would take for Blender to do it if was during rendering so it is not clearly working as I asked people they told me that this is supposed to be faster solution.
[image]

This file has no assets in it , just the mesh of my project .
So u can slap a default texture of ur choice
(the file with assets was like 70 mb)

Comment: If so, please file a bug report (Help > Report a Bug) *or* add a blend file to your question so we can identify potential user errors. At the moment "your question" is not really a question it's just some kind of "rant". Please take your time: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @brockmann added file

Comment: It may not be related, but in your file, you're using Render time denoising + compositing denoising. You don't need both. If you're having trouble with the Denoise node in the compositor, you can just delete it

Comment: Works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn9A6.gif - you forgot to pack the images so it's pink. The single bucket/tile which is running through the entire image after the rendering is done that's *render time denoising (Sampling> Denoising)*. It's a huge improvement, don't you agree? Nothing happens afterwards because the image is already "denoised". Your are trying to denoise the image again in the compositor (I'd suggest disable *render time denoising*). Note: Your sample count and max bounces are set way too low to render this properly, bump up the render samples to at least 500 for interior.

Comment: ... and as you hopefully can see now: it was impossible to answer your rant for the lack of essential details to understand the issue (without your blend). How are we supposed to know that you're using the denoiser twice? Again, please take your time when asking a question (see the link in my first comment), try to provide all relevant details and avoid fancy abbreviations like "u" or "ur". You might think that's cool but it doesn't help much just as rant doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

> what happens is when I add the denoiser to the render layer in compositor ,it hangs my laptop for roughly the same amount of time it would take for Blender to do it if was during rendering so it is not clearly working as I asked people they told me that this is supposed to be faster solution.

That's not exactly how it works. It doesn't actually make the rendering go faster. The node uses an algorithm to reduce the amount of noise in the final image, in post processing, so it just allows you to use a much smaller number of 'render samples' that would usually result in a very noisy final image, and make the image 'smoother' (with less noise). **Less samples = faster render**.

(go into render settings tab, under "sampling" and reduce the number or "Render" samples)

[image]

Some notes:

- If the number of samples is too low the resulting image will tend to look blurry and smudged, so it's not good to reduce **too much** the number of samples.
- It's not so good with refractions, so if you're rendering objects made of glass or transparent liquids, it may look a little weird.
- the denoising node effect is only applied after the imagem is completely rendered, so it may still look noisy while it's rendering.

Edit: In the render properties tab there is also a denoise option that you can enable. It denoises the image while rendering. If that is enabled, you don't need to add the node in the composite, it won't work because the rendered image will already be denoised.

Comment: I have actually done that probably in my provided while it was a mistake that I left it enabled but what is happening is that after a 15 minute render it is is hanging and freezing for about 40 to 50 seconds and after that I see the Denoised image ,on the contrary when I see a YouTube video of that happening for example one from CG matter or southernshorty 3D i see that its happening almost instantaneously after dropping in , the node. Does that the GPU on the CPU power play a role in this?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is happening because of it being an architectural scene and that it is actually demanding higher samples for example thousand

Comment: Yes, I would think GPU/CPU power play a role in how long it takes. Also the size of the image will obviously play a big role. If you have a GPU make sure it is being used to render in the render properties tab (it's much faster than CPU).
Any way, adding 45 seconds to a 15 minute render is still better than a 40 minute render with more samples, right?